# How to set height of the views in percentage of parent view size

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, percentage, aspect-ratio

I have 4 views and I want them to occupy 40 %,15%,15%,20% and I want 2 % space among them and 2% space to top and bottom layout.

I am confused on what constraint to use and how to use ?

like can *aspect ratio* be used for this like that ?

If I could set it in px I can do easily ,but its percetage there it gets tricky

Is it possible if i set it in px it will get translated to percentage according to screen size

Regards,

Appu

Comment: could you post some code or a code snippet?

Comment: Its basically on storyboard ... a four rectangle view one after another from top to bottom

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `Equal` constraint and set the percentages in the multiplier.

[image: Equal Constraint]

Assuming you have 1 view controller and 1 view in it, <kbd>control</kbd> + click (or right click) and drag from view to view controller, and choose equal (width | height).

[image: Contextual]

After that, go to the size inspector on the right side and click edit on the constraint you just added and change your multiplier.

[image: Edit]

Unrelated:
Aspect ratio is when you want to constrain the size of a view to a certain ratio (*W:H*). `1:1` would mean width is equal to height. `1:3` means height is 3 times your width.

Size classes is when you want to use different designs for different devices sizes. [Read more on size classes here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html)

Comment: If you don't mind can you tell me step by step,like what to press and where to drag and drop to get equal constraint, I am newbie to this

Comment: Can ya tell me usage of aspect ratio,size classes cuz some people asked me to do that ...hope you bear my ignorance and explain me regardless of whether its related with current requirement

Comment: I would appreciate your help by reviewing your posts once I get voting authorisatin